# implementation of radio buttons in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to implement radio buttons in my project. Since ready made control is not available for it, hence I've created simple buttons and set their image, which changes when they're clicked. Now I want that when I click on them, appropriate values should be assigned to strings, which in turn, are updated into the sqlite database. The code is as follows:

The method for radio button for marital status:

```
-(IBAction)maritalStatusRadioButton:(id)sender
{


    if(mMaritalRadioButton.isHighlighted)
    {

        [self radioButtonClick:sender];
    }
}
```

The method for Male/Female radio button:

```
-(IBAction)genderMaleRadioButton:(id)sender
{
    if(mMaleRadioButton.isHighlighted){
        mFemaleRadioButton.enabled = NO;

       // [sender setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio_button_on.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [self radioButtonClick:sender];
    }else if (mFemaleRadioButton.isHighlighted){
        mMaleRadioButton.enabled = NO;
        [self radioButtonClick:sender];

    }
```

radioButtonClick method:

```
-(void) radioButtonClick:(id)sender
{
     [sender setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio_button_on.png"]forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Update method:

```
-(IBAction)saveUserProfile
{
    sqlite3_stmt *statement;
    const char *dbpath = [mDatabasePath UTF8String];

    if (sqlite3_open(dbpath, &mDiary) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        NSString *marital = [[NSString alloc]init];  //holds marital status of user
        NSString  *gender = [[NSString alloc]init];  //used to determine if user has entered male or female gender

        if (mMaritalRadioButton.isHighlighted) {
            marital = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Married"];
        }
        else{
            marital  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Unmarried"];
        } 
        if(mMaleRadioButton.isHighlighted)
        {
            gender = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Male"];
        }else{
            gender = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Female"];
        }
        NSString *dummy = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",self.getUserName];
        //NSLog(@"dummy string is %@",dummy);

        NSString *updateSQL = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                               @"UPDATE USERDETAIL SET mUname = \"%@\", mImage = \"%@\", mGender = \"%@\", mDob = \"%@\", mEmail = \"%@\", mAddress = \"%@\", mLatitude = \"%@\", mLongitude = \"%@\",mMaritalStatus = \"%@\" WHERE mUserName = \"%@\" ", mUname.text, @"", gender, @"", mEmail.text, mAddress.text, mLatitude.text,mLongitude.text,marital, dummy];
               const char *update_stmt = [updateSQL UTF8String];
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(mDiary, update_stmt,
                           -1, &statement, NULL);
        if (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_DONE)
       {
            mStatus.text = @"user profile updated";
            mUname.text = @"";
           // mPassword.text = @"";
            //mImage.text = @"";
            mGender.text = @"";
            //mDob.date = @"";
            mEmail.text = @"";
            mAddress.text = @"";
            //mMaritalStatus.text = @"";
            mLatitude.text = @"";
            mLongitude.text = @"";


        } else {
            mStatus.text = @"Failed to update user profile";
        }

        sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        sqlite3_close(mDiary);
    }

}
```

The problem is that in `saveUserProfile` method the conditions `mMaritalRadioButton.isHighlighted` and `mMaleRadioButton.isHighlighted` are never true. Hence only Female and Unmarried are getting stored. Male and Married are never stored. There is no problem in the image change. Can any one help in solving it?
                 Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

isHighlighted is for checking a temporary state, when you tap on a button it'll be highlighted means a blue color will appear on the button. It's temporary so you can't rely on it.

Instead of:

```
if(mMaritalRadioButton.isHighlighted)
```

use:

```
if([[UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio_button_on.png"] isEqual:mMaleRadioButton.currentImage])
```

Comment: why compare images? the selected property is made for this, no!?

Comment: @Daij-Djan: If you need to use selected property, you need to set the selected property to yes or no when you click on it.

Comment: you don't need to create another UIImage instance just for comparison.

Comment: Thanks very much... it's working absolutely fine now. Can you please tell me what exactly the problem was, in my code?

Comment: @Crazed'n'Dazed we all did ^^ isHighlighted is wrong. it is only for drawing and not kept. Checking the image is not very robust

Comment: @Daij-Djan: yes, that is cleaner, but there is one more code is needed. He is implementing radio button, so if one button is selected you need to set the selected property of other buttons to no

Comment: no, keep a reference to the selectButton and deselect that. I'd wrap it in a property

Answer (score 3):

```
//Radio Button : Tap on this each time will toggle its state.


//// Initialization...

UIButton *radioButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10,10,100,100)];

[radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unSelected.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

[radioButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selected.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];


////// target method 

-(void)on_click_button:(id)sender
{
  UIButton *button = (UIButton*)sender;

  [button setSelected:!button.isSelected];

  if(button.isSelected)
  {
     //Write your code on selected state here...
  }
  else
     {
        //Write your code on un-selected state here...
     }

}
```

Comment: forControlState => forState

Answer (score 1):

#### because `isHiglighted` is the wrong property.

```
Discussion
Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether the control is highlighted when it is drawn.
```

the important part is **when drawn**

---

#### you need `isSelected`

```
Discussion
Specify YES if the control is selected; otherwise NO. The default is NO. For many controls, this state has no effect on behavior or appearance. But other subclasses (for example, UISwitchControl) or the application object might read or set this control state.
```

note that you have to **manually set it in your IBAction**

Comment: Thanks for the reply... but this isn't working. I changed the staement in radioClickButton: [sender setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio_button_on.png"]forState:UIControlStateSelected]; No change.. and now the image too is not changing.

Answer (score 0):

@Daij-Djan is right, you need `isSelected`, not `isHighlighted`.

`isHighlighted` is used when user has pressed down on the button, but hasn't released the touch yet.

In addition, you don't need to change image every time like this, instead add a image for the `UIControlStateSelected` like this:

```
[button setImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"Radio_button_on.png"]
        forState: UIControlStateSelected];
```